# Is anyone familiar with .BMT files and their structure?

Tags: bmp

This might be in the wrong place here but I am trying to use a simple BMP Image in a software for thermography called IRSoft. Is anyone maybe familiar with the file type .BMT?

I don't really want to reverse engineer too much but maybe someone else has an idea.

Answer (score 1):

In the status line of IRSoft you can see the resolution of your camera. In my case it is 160x120 pixels. My BMT-files have always a size of 230588 bytes, that means some 12 bytes per pixel...

It seems to me that the last 160*120*4=76800 bytes of the BMT-file represents the thermal image:
4 bytes for every pixel. At file offset 153788 I can find the upper left pixel followed by the rest of the upper line. At the last offset 230584 I can find the lower right pixel.
I don't know the meaning of the rest of the file. Perhaps the real image, reference temperatures...

Do you know how to calculate the temperature out of these values?

This table translates the 4 byte values approximately to temperatures in degrees Celsius:
I am afraid they differ to other files.
0x41d00000 and more: 26.0°C an more
0x41c00000 and more: 24.0°C an more
0x41b00000 and more: 22.0°C an more
0x41a00000 and more: 20.0°C an more
0x41900000 and more: 18.0°C an more